# NullPointerException by flyway migration in OC4J

Tags: flyway, oc4j

I use flyway-core-4.2.0 for database migration, when I deploy my ear file in OC4J with java7, I face to the following exception:

```
[2018-07-10 09:00:12:074- INFO][Thread:Orion Launcher] (ApacheCommonsLog.java:43-->info)- Flyway 4.2.0 by Boxfuse
[2018-07-10 09:00:12:090- INFO][Thread:Orion Launcher] (ApacheCommonsLog.java:43-->info)- Database: jdbc:oracle:thin:@database.officeauto.net:1521:orcl (Oracle 11.1)
[2018-07-10 09:00:12:436- INFO][Thread:Orion Launcher] (ApacheCommonsLog.java:43-->info)- Current version of schema "GAM_ARCHIVE_DMSDEV": 1
[2018-07-10 09:00:12:809- INFO][Thread:Orion Launcher] (ApacheCommonsLog.java:43-->info)- Migrating schema "GAM_ARCHIVE_DMSDEV" to version 1.1.0 - baselineSchema
[2018-07-10 09:00:12:818-ERROR][Thread:Orion Launcher] (UpdateDataBase.java:3556-->runDatabaseMigration)- error in database migration(by FlyWay) null
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.getNumRows(T4C8Oall.java:737) ~[classes12dms.jar:"Oracle JDBC Driver version - 10.1.0.4.2"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.execute_for_rows(T4CStatement.java:564) ~[classes12dms.jar:"Oracle JDBC Driver version - 10.1.0.4.2"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1153) ~[classes12dms.jar:"Oracle JDBC Driver version - 10.1.0.4.2"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1647) ~[classes12dms.jar:"Oracle JDBC Driver version - 10.1.0.4.2"]
    at com.evermind.sql.FilterStatement.execute(FilterStatement.java:27) ~[oc4j.jar:?]
    at com.evermind.sql.FilterStatement.execute(FilterStatement.java:27) ~[oc4j.jar:?]
    at com.evermind.sql.StatementBCELProxy.execute(StatementBCELProxy.java:240) ~[oc4j.jar:?]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate.executeStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:267) ~[flyway-core-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript.execute(SqlScript.java:142) ~[flyway-core-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationExecutor.execute(SqlMigrationExecutor.java:76) ~[flyway-core-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.doMigrateGroup(DbMigrate.java:343) ~[flyway-core-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.access$900(DbMigrate.java:53) ~[flyway-core-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$4.call(DbMigrate.java:276) ~[flyway-core-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:75) ~[flyway-core-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.applyMigrations(DbMigrate.java:273) ~[flyway-core-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.access$800(DbMigrate.java:53) ~[flyway-core-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.call(DbMigrate.java:210) ~[flyway-core-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.call(DbMigrate.java:146) ~[flyway-core-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.DbSupport$1.call(DbSupport.java:223) ~[flyway-core-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:75) ~[flyway-core-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.DbSupport.lock(DbSupport.java:219) ~[flyway-core-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl.lock(MetaDataTableImpl.java:174) ~[flyway-core-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrate(DbMigrate.java:146) ~[flyway-core-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1010) ~[flyway-core-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:971) ~[flyway-core-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1464) ~[flyway-core-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:971) ~[flyway-core-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at com.gam.archive.dbutil.UpdateDataBase.runDatabaseMigration(UpdateDataBase.java:3534) [archive-lib.jar:?]
```

I updated fylway version to 5.1.4 but this exception was not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=185245 it states:

> The stacktrace resembles a known fault in the JDBC driver which occur
>   when a oracle function is call using upper case "CALL" in the
>   statement.
>
> Instead of  "{ ? = CALL foo(?) }"
>
> change to: "{ ? = call foo(?) }"
>
> or update JDBC driver.